# Check if username already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want validate if username already exists while user insert the username in textbox or just after the textbox lost focus.

Jquery or Ajax?
Please, someone have examples of that?

Comment: "Jquery or Ajax?" — "Ford Focus or Driving?"

Comment: This question is perfect example of please-do-my-homework. And I wont pay you

Comment: @Jashwant - also known as "Plz gives me teh codez"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onblur event of the text box, get the value of textbox and using jQuery ajax, make a call to a server page where you check it and return appropriate results. based on the results show the message to user (Available or Not Available)

Include jQuery in your page and have this script also

```
$(function(){
  $("#txtUserName").blur(function() {
     var userName=$(this).val();
     if(userName!="")
     {
       $.get("checkusername.aspx?username="+userName+"&t="+$.now(),function(data){
           if(data=="1")
           {
             $("#msgDiv").html("Not Available");             
           } 
           else
           {
             $("#msgDiv").html("Available :) ");
           } 

       });    
     }    
  });   

});
```

Assumuing `checkusername.aspx` page will read the querystring value and check in the database and return(Response.Write()) "1" or "0"

I prefer to use a Generic handler (.ASHX file) to do the server side checking instead of using the aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

Use jQuery to react to the [onblur event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) for the textbox.  Then, use jQuery to make an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to a controller to see if the user name is already taken.

```
$('#usernameTextBox').blur(function() {
  alert('Make your ajax call here.');
});
```

Comment: do you have an example with source code of that?

Comment: Not a complete working sample but I provided snippets and a link to the relevant jQuery docs.